# NsisIIS plugin baggage

Tags: iis-7, nsis

When I invoke NsisIIS on the target machine, I get:

Could not load: C:\Users\goldend\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw48B9.tmp\NsisIIS.dll

DependencyWalker Yields:

LoadLibraryExA("C:\Users\goldend\AppData\Local\Temp\nsx5A94.tmp\NsisIIS.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).

I have installed the VS2010 redistributables....

Answer (score 0):

Either install all dependencies (.net framework, VC++ Runtime etc.) before using the plug-in on target machine
or
recompile the plugin (if possible).

I cannot see anything special except **activeds.dll**. Make sure this dll exists on target machine.